# Node/Typescript Object is possibly null project won't build

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying to build a node/typescript projects but it just aborts with this error:

> error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'

```
const mycontent = mydata.match(/(\[[^\[\]]+?\])\s*(.+)$/);
```

The error points to this line below:

```
const partcontent = mycontent[1]; // Error points here
```

How can I stop this error from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no match, the `.match` method will return `null`. Try to explicitly test for `null`:

```
const mycontent = mydata.match(/(\[[^\[\]]+?\])\s*(.+)$/);
if (mycontent !== null)  {
  const partcontent = mycontent[1];
}
```